# How to abstract dash plotly component into another file with a callback?

Tags: python, django, callback, plotly-dash

Currently, I have my application python file separated with the specific component in the Django framework.

I have seen a lot of examples writing each component with callback in the same file with the app python file. I am wondering how to write the update_output_div() function in a file with callback and let the app call it? Thank you so much!

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
...
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-input', component_property='value')
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'Output: {}'.format(input_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that takes your `app` as a parameter and put your decorated function inside this function:

```
def init_callback(app):
    @app.callback(
        Output(component_id="my-output", component_property="children"),
        Input(component_id="my-input", component_property="value"),
    )
    def update_output_div(input_value):
        return "Output: {}".format(input_value)
```

Then you could call the function like this after defining `app.layout` like this:

```
init_callback(app)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created 3 files to encapsulate the html component. 1. app 2. layout (import both app and function with callback) 3. function with callback (import app), and this resolved my issue.